# the case of url percent encoding

Tags: javascript, url-encoding

In [this](http://www.sislands.com/coin70/week6/encoder.htm) page, it is possible  to decode

`Some+website+you+got%21%0AGood+luck+%28you%27ll+need+it%29%0A%7E%7E+The+Slug+%7E%7E`

into

```
Some website you got!
Good luck (you'll need it)
~~ The Slug ~~
```

But what if i have something like `%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%` (only percent codes, no letters)??

How do i decode it?

Is it ASCII?

What is the meaning of url percent encoding? Why can't we do without it?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/). Conversely, there are `decode*()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Because some of the characters are invalid in URLs. To decode any URL component in JavaScript to normal text, use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

The decoding process is no different, whether it is composed of a combination of letters and escape codes or solely of escape codes. Also, it doesn't have to be ASCII - it could be any encoding, but I believe it's usually UTF-8.

Comment: thanks! i tried this --> http://jsbin.com/iyipir/edit#javascript,html   It doesn't work! Please, show the right way to do it.

Comment: some of the characters are invalid in URLs. Does specification tell it?? Which one??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: Google "invalid URL characters," though it shouldn't matter - if you ever need a list of invalid characters, you're not making good use of built-in functions. Anyway, there are a couple problems. 1) [It needs to be a string](http://jsbin.com/iyipir/3/edit#source) and 2) that's a malformed escape sequence. Are those random characters, or only some of a real one? Because those don't make any characters.

Comment: When i encode it http://jsbin.com/iyipir/4/edit, i get - http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F  But i 'd like to get only percent codes. how can i do that??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: I wrote a custom encoding function to do that: http://jsbin.com/iyipir/5/edit